# Encrypting / Decrypting Lists of data efficiently

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I have an encrypted JSON object which holds a list of data that is encrypted using AES and RSA encryption.

```
<?php

    function decrypt_data($encrypted_data, $session_key)
    {
        $decrypt = explode('|', $encrypted_data);
        $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
        $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $session_key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);

        return $decrypted;
    }

    function encrypt_session_key($session_key)
    {
        $sealed ="";
        $ekeys="";
        $pubKey[] = openssl_pkey_get_public("file:///public.pem");
        $result = openssl_seal($session_key, $sealed, $ekeys, $pubKey);
        $encrypted_session_key = array( 'encdata' => base64_encode($sealed), 'enckey' => base64_encode(serialize($ekeys)) );
        return $encrypted_session_key;
    }

    $data = '{"index":{"12345":{"title":"title 1","date_modified":1029232323},"23456":{"title":"title 2","date_modified":1029232323}},"archived":{}}';
    $session_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
    $encrypted_data = encrypt_data($session_key, $data);
    $encrypted_session_key = encrypt_session_key($session_key);
    $session_key = null;
    $encrypted_session_key_data = $encrypted_session_key['encdata'];
    $encrypted_session_key_keys = $encrypted_session_key['enckey'];

    // the encrypted data
    $the_encrypted_data = array("data_key" => $encrypted_session_key_data, "encryption_data_key" => $encrypted_session_key_keys, "data" => $encrypted_data);
?>
```

Every time a user loads their dashboard, I decrypt the data and list it in a table using [dataTables](http://datatables.net).

```
<?php

    function decrypt_session_key($encrypted_session, $env_key)
    {
        $private_key = openssl_get_privatekey("file:///private.pem", "password");
        openssl_open(base64_decode($encrypted_session), $open, unserialize(base64_decode($env_key))[0], $private_key);

        return $open;
    }

    function decrypt_data($encrypted_data, $session_key)
    {
        $decrypt = explode('|', $encrypted_data);
        $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
        $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $session_key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
        return $decrypted;
    }

    $decrypted_key = decrypt_session_key($data_key, $encryption_data_key);
    $the_decrypted_data = json_decode(decrypt_data($data, $decrypted_key), true);

?>
```

When there is about 10-100+ items on the list, it takes a good 8-10 seconds for the list to load, I'm assuming because it is taking a while to decrypt the data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this whole process a bit faster as my forms add up? I don't want it taking a LONG time once I have 1000 or even 10,000 pieces of data in this list.

The only stipulation is, the data **must** be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time is likely be taken by the RSA decryption of the session keys. RSA is much slower than AES. Probably the best thing to do is to create a session single key for multiple fields and decrypt that once. Currently they are all dependent on the same private key anyway, so it would not matter much with regards to key management. You are already providing a random IV for each field, so the encryption itself should be safe.

Another small change that you could make is to actually use AES. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits instead of 128 bits. Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_1282`)is equal to AES - currently you would not be able to decrypt with an AES only library. The key size depends on the size of the session key.

Another fix could be to switch to an Elliptic Curve EC key pair and use ECIES. This is much faster for decryption (and only slightly slower for encryption). This would require a steep learning curve if you don't know Elliptic Curve cryptography yet.

Finally, OpenSSL would be faster on Intel platforms compared to mcrypt, which does not support AES-NI instruction set (currently and to my knowledge - the C-lib has not been updated for years on end). However, the PHP OpenSSL API is very limited and currently I would not be able to assist here.

Comment: Note: I've not performed a complete code review over the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use multiple ajax request to simulate multithreading decryption.